# How to create a table with 2 columns to display data in flutter? one column which has static data and other with empty fields which can be edited

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been looking into it for a long time and could not find exactly what I need.it must look something like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhSFY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridView with crossAxisCount: 2, and then just add widgets in like any listview.

Docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html